# Elasticsearch: Class Cast Exception Scala API

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

> I have been using ES 5.6 and the aggregation queries are working
> fine. Recently, we upgraded our ES to 7.1 and it has resulted in a
> ClassCastException for one of the queries. I'm posting the ES Index
> mapping along with the Scala code and ES query that is resulting in
> the exception.

Mapping:

```
  {
        "orgs": {
            "mappings": {
                "org": {
                    "properties": {
                        "people": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "email": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "first_name": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "raw": {
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "last_name": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "raw": {
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "pcsi": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "position": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "raw": {
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "position_type": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "source_guid": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "source_lni": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "suffix": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Scala Query:

```
  baseQuery.aggs(nestedAggregation("people", OrganizationSchema.People)
          .subAggregations(termsAgg("positiontype", "people.position_type")))
```

Elastic Query:

```
{"query":{"term":{"_id":{"value":"id"}}},"aggs":{"people":{"nested":{"path":"people"},"aggs":{"positiontype":{"terms":{"field":"people.position_type"}}}}}}



response: 
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "people": {
      "doc_count": 52,
      "positiontype": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Board Member",
            "doc_count": 28
          },
          {
            "key": "Executive",
            "doc_count": 22
          },
          {
            "key": "Others",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Scala code:

```
def getOrganizationPeopleFilters(client: ElasticClient, entityType: String, entityId: String, request: Option[PostFilterApiRequest], baseQuery: SearchRequest): IO[PostFilters] = {
    val q = baseQuery.aggs(nestedAggregation("people", OrganizationSchema.People)
      .subAggregations(termsAgg("positiontype", "people.position_type")))
    client.execute {
      q
   }.flatMap { res ⇒
      esToJsonOrganizationPeopleFilters(res.result)
    }
  }
```

The ES query is running and aggregating correctly in Kibana. But, when we are trying to **FlatMap** the response in the above Scala api code, it is resulting in a ClassCastException (java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer)